# Extracting only number in a string from a starting point

Tags: java, string, decoding, huffman-code

Suppose I'm taking a string from a file that has decoded huffman text and the frequency of the characters inside it.Example the taken string is:"000111010 h:2#c:1"
I want to take only 2 and 1 and put them into an arrayList of integers called frequencies.
This is the method I have written for it but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public void extractFrequency() {
     char[] stringArray= new char[finalText.length()];
     stringArray=finalText.toCharArray();
     boolean startingNow=false;
     
     for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i=+3) {
        
        if(stringArray[i]==' ')
            startingNow=true;
        
        if(startingNow=true) {
            frequencies.add((int)stringArray[i]);
            i++;
        }
        }
    System.out.println(frequencies);
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is it that you want to extract from string `"000111010 h:2#c:1"`.

Comment: If the format is always going to look like that, I'd probably use regex: `.*h:(?<h>[\d]+)#c:(?<c>[\d]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with checking `startingNow` is true, check whether the current character is a digit or not. If it is a digit, then add it to the list. But I don't understand why you are doing `i+=3` in loop. This might work for you. I am subtracting 48 while adding it to the list, to obtain the original digit, as in Character systems '0' starts from 48.

```
public void extractFrequency() {
     char[] stringArray= new char[finalText.length()];
     stringArray=finalText.toCharArray();
     boolean startingNow=false;
     
     for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        
        if(stringArray[i]==' ')
            startingNow=true;
        
        if(startingNow==true && Character.isDigit(stringArray[i])) {//should be startingNow==true not startingNow=true
            frequencies.add(stringArray[i] - 48);
        }
        }
    System.out.println(frequencies);
}
```

Comment: No idea if this matters, but this will only work if the numbers after `h` and `c` are _always_ one digit.  For example `h:10` will add `{1, 0}` to the `List`.  Additionally, negatives won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have an error in your code `if(startingNow=true)` should be `if(startingNow==true)`

Comment: That makes sense...Thanks!